# How do I create a distributable Docker image?

Tags: node.js, linux, docker

I'd like to build a NodeJS server packaged as an executable, which can then be installed and run on any Linux machine without any pre-requisite dependencies. I was considering packaging it as a Docker image, but that would mean that the user would need Docker to be installed on their system. Is there a way to package a Docker image itself as an executable, so that all the user needs to do is to run an executable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With docker NO

**The answer for the executable from docker is no.**

> You can create docker/docker-compose project which you can simply run
> if you have docker installed.

## Without docker YES

**But you can still package it without using docker (with the whole nodejs included in the executable).**

> Look at this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg

Comment: (You can also just `npm install && npm run start` if you have Node installed; this is probably strictly easier than installing Docker.)

Comment: @DavidMaze of course he can do that, but he wants an executable :) so it has to be packaged with NodeJS as well